# Is it possible to add a declarations file to an untyped package without registering to @types?

Tags: typescript

I am able to add types to a package i am importing by adding a declaration file in the root of the project that is doing the importing:

```
index.d.ts

declare module "@org/client" { 
  export = client;

  ...
}
```

This works. But I'll need to do it in all projects that import the module.

Can I put this information into the package that is being imported instead somehow? I have tried to put the `index.d.ts` in the imported package instead of in the importing project, but the types are not picked up when I do that.

Comment: I think you have to define a `<some-path>/<some-name>.d.ts` file aside every `<some-path>/<some-name>.js` file

Comment: @GuerricP thanks, that was a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Is the package you're importing a public package that lacks types? If so, the best approach is to contribute the types to `DefinitelyTyped`, so that the entire community may benefit from it. As your question is phrased, mentioning "without registering to `@types`", I'm not sure if you explicitly do NOT want to do this for some reason? If so, why?

If you have several projects using a module that lacks types and you need those types in all places - and for some reason you don't want to contribute the types - the only other ways I can think of that doesn't involve pasting the same type declaration into every single project is 1) make a pull request to the library to add the types natively into it or 2) fork the library and add the required .d.ts files directly to it. Each of these approaches also require you to point the `"types"` directive in `package.json` to the `.d.ts` file(s) in question.

Comment: It's a private package

Comment: Then why not simply add the types directly to it?